# Geometry Nodes: Coordinates system based on edge loop

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

How could I create a coordinate system in GN based on an edge loop selection?
I've selected the top edge loop of this mesh and I want it to map the coordinates system Z component. Something like the attached image but I need it completely parallel to the vertices selection.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE GIF: something like this but without loosing its parallelity with the top vertices.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just on the one face / selection? Or across many? Always in Z? Sorry, a lot of questions. Perhaps cleared up by getting an idea of how you want to use this.

Comment: What's "parallel to the vertices selection"?

Comment: I don't get this. None of this makes sense to me. The question would certainly benefit from a better explanation, more examples of what the end goal could be or what it is going to be used for...

Comment: Across al the hole mesh, Robin. And yes just in Z component.

Comment: Martynas I mean parallel to the top vertices selection. As you can see in the first image, the shading line is almost parallel to the top vertices. I would like:
- first make it completely parallel
-second: make it slide along the Z component.

Comment: I've updated the question with a GIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i am not totally sure what you want, but i hope it is this:

[image]

but...i made a copy of your "roof", raycasted to that copy so i got the distance from each point to that roof and used that as y distance/coordinate.

To normalize the values i divided by the max bounds z value.

node tree:

[image]

[image]

[image]

--- update

thinking about it...i could even get the roof by gn like this, so i don't have to create the extra object:

[image]

note: this works only, if the edge loop is the roof...and the vertices are all straight up, so don't know whether this helps you

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Chris!

Comment: you are welcome